# Print values from javascript object

Tags: javascript

Here is my object ,

```
ocenia=["-23.725012", "-11.350797", "-45.460131"]
```

I want to print elements of object `ocenia`.

What i am trying to do is ,

```
for ( i in ocenia)
   {
      console.log(i)
   }
```

It is just printing indexes of elements like ,

```
0 
1 
2
```

Whats wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: [Why for in loops for arrays are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Note that `ocenia` is not an object, but an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please please please [**don't iterate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) over JS Arrays with `for..in`. It's slow and tend to cause strange bugs when someone decides to augment `Array.prototype`. Just use old plain `for`:

```
for (var i = 0, l = ocenia.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(ocenia[i]);
}
```

... or, if you're among the happy guys who don't have to worry about IE8-, more concise [**Array.prototype.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
ocenia.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   for ( i in ocenia)
   {
      console.log(ocenia[i])
   }
```

for array you should use `for (;;)` loop

```
for(var i=0, len = ocenia.length; i < len; i++){
       console.log(ocenia[i]);
}
```

OR   `forEach` (recommended )

```
ocenia.forEach(function(item, index){
   console.log(item)
});
```

Comment: For...in loops for arrays is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
for ( i in ocenia)
{
    console.log(ocenia[i]);
}
```

which means to get the `i`th element of `ocenia`.

P.S. it's an array, not object. And never iterate over arrays with `for..in`. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Use this for the best practice:

```
for (var i = 0, len = ocenia.length; i < len; i++)
{
    console.log(ocenia[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following code

```
console.log(oceania[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for ( i in ocenia)
   {
      console.log(i)
   }
```

do

```
for ( i in ocenia)
   {
      console.log(ocenia[i])
   }
```

Comment: For...in loops for arrays is a bad idea.